Launcher or whatever to limit user actions (for elderly)
My mother is a disabled person. She can't go out due to health issues. Her Android smartphone is the only way to communicate with the World (my brother, who lives abroad, her relatives, her friends etc). While she's not an advanced smartphone user, she plays with the phone a lot, what ends up with apps being deleted, contacts being blocked or removed, new unneeded subscriptions and so on. And she even does not realise, that she does all these (she says “the phone did this by itself”). This creates a lot of problems for me and nurses as we need to install and fix things all the time.
Is there any app, like a launcher, that can help dealing with this? I mean, at least the app should deny deleting apps, what is, probably, the biggest problem. Another contact/phone app, that would not allow blocking contacts, would be handy too. That's another big problem.
I thought about setting up Family Link, but, as far as I know, it does not prevent apps from being deleted. I considered also kid's launchers, but they usually limit, what can be launched, and I need to limit “management” functions.
Note, that I don't need a launcher for elderly, that makes things big and have a simple interface. I need an app to prevent some actions like deleting WhatsApp and don't care if this is simple to do or not.

I am using Nova because my pocket was doing some of these things. The home screen gets locked. And requires a long press on the screen followed by a long press on a lock icon to unlock it. I would definitely give it a go.


Does Nova prevent removal of apps? Maybe, it's possible to protect this function by a password? My mother removes apps on purpose (I believe, she thinks, she cleans system in this way, i.e., removes occupied temporary space, not apps themselves). I was trying to explain not to do so, but she forgets or whatever (she's not healthy). So, making it harder to unlock the home screen won't help, unfortunately. This will only make her nervous.
